# Get return value from function in another Class

Tags: javascript, sqlite, react-native, expo

How can I get the return value of a function in another class:

I have a class with some SQLite request and I'm calling this class from another class like this:

```
import lotManager from '../components/LotManager';

class LotView extends React.Component {
    async loadLot(id) {
        await console.log('retvalue', lotManager.testIt(id));
    }

    render() {
        this.loadLot(12);
        return (
            // some code
        );
    }
}
```

And my SQL class :

```
const db = SQLite.openDatabase("db.db");

class LotManager extends Component {
   getLotById = (id) => {
        db.transaction(tx => {
            tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM LOTS WHERE ID = ?", [id],
                function (tx, results) {
                    // results is the value i actually want to get
                    return results;
                },
                function (tx, error) { console.log("Error SELECT : ", error.message) }
            );
        });
    }
}

const lotManager = new LotManager();
export default lotManager;
```

### My question :

What is the best way to get my SQLite request function result to my class? For now I can interact with the function but no way to get a return value (i understand why this code doesn't work it's just there to explain what i want).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you mean with *to my class*? Store it in a property? Or get a return value from the `tx.executeSql` callback?

Comment: The return value from the tx.executeSql is fine. What i want is to get that results value to the LotView Class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap a `Promise` around your `db.transaction` function and return the promise. Resolve or reject whenever the inner callbacks have are finished.

```
class LotManager extends Component {
    getLotById = (id) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.transaction(tx => {
            tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM LOTS WHERE ID = ?", [id],
                function(tx, results) {
                    resolve(results);
                },
                function(tx, error) {
                    reject("Error SELECT : ", error.message);
                }
            );
        });
    });
}
```

Now you can get your values in either a `then` and `catch` syntax.

```
const lotManager = new LotManager();
lotManager.getLotById(420)
   .then(results => console.log(results))
   .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Or store it in a variable with `async` / `await`.

```
(async () => {
  const lotManager = new LotManager();
  const results = await lotManager.getLotById(420);
  console.log(results);
}());
```

Comment: Exactly what i wanted. Working perfectly for me. Thanks !